# Integral solutions to $a^3x^3+a^2x^2+ax+a=0$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I have to determine every possible nonzero $a\in\Bbb{Z}$
for which the equation below has an integral solution $x\in\Bbb{Z}$.
I guess it is a functional equation.

This is the equation:

$$a^3x^3 + a^2x^2 + ax + a = 0$$

I have done this so far:

$$a(a^2x^3 + ax^2 + x + 1) =0    $$

$$a^2x^3 + ax^2 + x + 1 = 0$$

If I follow the comment below the root rational theorem says that $a_0$ is divisible by  $p$ and  $a_n$  is divisible by  $q$

So I end up with:

$a^2 = p$

$1 = q$

Because:

$x_0=\tfrac{p}{q}$

while:

$p,q \in\Bbb{Z}$

Then:

$x_0 =\tfrac{a^2}{1}$

All whole numerical divisors of

$\tfrac{a^2}{1}$

which is the same as $a^2$,

are possible solutions.
I still don't get how to continue.

Comment: You cannot divide by $x$ until you have necessarily assumed $x\neq0$.

Comment: Since $a\neq 0$ we can divide by $a$ to get $a^2x^3+ax^2+x+1=0$.  Now invoke the rational root theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you have misapplied the rational root theorem; if
$$a^2x^3+ax^2+x+1=0,$$
where $a$ is an integer and $x$ is rational, then if $x=\frac{p}{q}$ is in lowest terms then $p$ divides $1$ and $q$ divides $a^2$. This means $p=\pm1$ and $x$ is an integer if and only if also $q=\pm1$, in which case $x=\pm1$. Now the question remains; for which values of $a$ does the equation have a root $\pm1$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Reduce the derived equation
$$a^2 x^3 + a x^2 + x + 1 = 0$$ modulo $x$. (NB $x = 0$ never gives a solution.)

> This leaves $$1 \equiv 0 \pmod x,$$ so $x = \pm 1$. Substitute both of these possibilities into the derived equation and check whether the resulting equation has any (nonzero) integer solutions $a$.